# Why is this code not displaying properly?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

Why are the JLabel, JTextField and JButton components on the FieldBox panel not displaying?

Please let me know if I can add anything to this question to make it more answerable!

The field box (one of which is created for each of several instance fields):

```
public class FieldBox extends javax.swing.JPanel {
JLabel label;
JTextField textField;

public FieldBox() {
            setBackground(Color.RED);

    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    label = new JLabel();
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    add(label,gbc);

    textField = new JTextField();
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    add(textField, gbc);

    JButton editBtn = new JButton("edit");
    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    add(editBtn, gbc);        


    JButton saveBtn = new JButton ("save");
    gbc.gridx = 3;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    add(saveBtn, gbc);

    label.setVisible(true);
    label.setBackground(Color.yellow);


    setVisible(true);





    initComponents();
}
```

The panel onto which the boxes are added: (the panel appears. I know this panel loads because I can see its background. I can also see the "tit" JLabel, which I'm using for testing. Also, when I load the boxes onto it using a gridLayout (as shown below), I see the background of one of the boxes, but none of its contents are displayed, and also there should be three boxes shown but I only see one. Using a GridBagLayout

```
public class ShowBook extends javax.swing.JPanel {

public ShowBook(Book b) {
    setLayout(new GridLayout(1,6));
    setBackground(Color.GREEN);
       String[] fieldTitles = {"title",  "catalog", "publisher" };
    JLabel tit = new JLabel("tit");

    add(tit);


    for (String s : fieldTitles){
        FieldBox fb = new FieldBox();
        fb.label.setText(s + ": ");
        fb.textField.setText(getField(b, s));     
        System.out.println("in text field" + fb.textField.getText());
        fb.revalidate();
        fb.setVisible(true);
        add (fb);


    }
    revalidate();
   setVisible(true);
}
```

The panel onto which the ShowBook panel (above) is added. This panel also contains a listbox, which lists books in the collection, and a button to launch a ShowBook panel with the selected book as parameter.

```
public class ShowLib extends javax.swing.JPanel {

/**
 * Creates new form ShowLib
 */
public ShowLib(Library l) {

    setLayout(new BorderLayout())  ;     
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    JPanel listPanel = new JPanel();
    listPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    final JList bookList = new JList();

    bookList.setVisible(true);
    bookList.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 600));
    bookList.setBackground(Color.yellow);

    DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();
    for (Book b : l.libList){
        dlm.addElement(b);
    }
    bookList.setModel(dlm);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.fill = gbc.BOTH;
    listPanel.add(bookList, gbc);

    JButton showBtn = new JButton("show");
    gbc.gridy = gbc.RELATIVE;
    listPanel.add(showBtn, gbc);


    showBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener () {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            Book b = (Book) bookList.getSelectedValue();
            ShowBook db = new ShowBook (b);
            System.out.println("Clicked");
            add (db, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            revalidate();
        }


    });





    revalidate();
    setVisible(true);

    add(listPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);  

}
```

Where the ShowLib panel is added to the main JFrame. I know this works because that panel displays properly

```
void showLib() {
    ShowLib sl = new ShowLib(l);
    sl.setVisible(true);
    setContentPane(sl);
    revalidate();
 //   this.revalidate();
//    this.pack();
    System.out.println("showlibClicked");
}
```

Comment: Is your code short, self-contained, correct, and runnable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the line `initComponents();` at the bottom of the FieldBox class.

Lesson learned: If you're not using NetBeans visual GUI editor, GET RID OF THIS LINE!

Comment: *"Lesson learned: If you're not using NetBeans visual GUI editor, GET RID OF THIS LINE!"*  This is nonsense.  If you understand what the IDE typically does in that method, you can code the apps. GUI construction within it.  It is quite common for people who use a mix of GUI designed and free form code to use the same basic structure and code signature for both.